# Redux: wait for an epic action to be finished

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-observable

I am using `react` + `redux` + `redux-observable`.

I have the following epic action:

```js
export const fetchCompaniesEpic = (action$: Observable<Action>): Observable<Action> =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType(FETCH_COMPANIES),
        take(1),
        switchMap((action: any) => WebServiceProxy.getCompanies().pipe(map((companies: Company[]) => fetchCompaniesFulfilled(companies))))
    );
```

Which does some async operation and then call the "normal action" with the results:

```js
export const fetchCompaniesFulfilled = (companies: Company[]) => ({ type: 'FETCH_COMPANIES_FULFILLED', companies });
```

Then inside my container I dispatch the epic action in this way:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps: any = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>, ownProps: any) => ({
    fetchCompanies: (): void => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_COMPANIES });
    }
});
```

All works like a charm but how can I know when the epic action will finish?

I would like to do something like `dispatch({ type: FETCH_COMPANIES }).subscribe(...)`

Comment: @streletss I am sorry I rejected the edit by mistake

Answer (score 0):

I eneded up with the following solution at the moment, and I am posting it in order to know your thoughts about it and to help someone else with the same issue.

I implemented a thunk which does what I am looking for.

This is the thunk action:

```js
export const fetchCompaniesThunk = () => {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        return fetchCompanies().pipe(map((companies: Company[]) => dispatch(fetchCompaniesFulfilled(companies))));
    };
};
```

This is the `fetchCompaniesFulfilled` action:

```js
export const fetchCompanies = (): Observable<any> => {
    return WebServiceProxy.getCompanies().pipe(take(1));
};
```

And from the container I can do:

```js
dispatch(fetchCompaniesThunk()).subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log('finished to fetch companies', data);
});
```

Even if the solution is working fine, I am not really satisfied. Or better my actual question is: why do I need `redux-observable`?